# Remove an added element with jquery

Tags: jquery, clone, addition

Two things that I'm trying to accomplish. 1) Using the clone method I want the user to be able to add multiple text box items with a delete link adjacent to the text box, not below it like it is working now. 2). When clicking the 'delete' link I want to remove the parent list item and delete link. I've looked around for an answer but not coming up with one. Also, if a method better than clone would work, I'm open for suggestions and explanations.

[My jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/squirc77/56wuv/):

```
$('#click').click(function(){
var clone = $('li:last').clone()
if(!clone.find('.del')[0]) clone.append('<a href="#" class="del">Delete</a>')

clone.appendTo('ul');
    });

$('ul').on('click', 'li .del', function(){
     $(this).closest('li').remove();
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See your updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/juanpastas/56wuv/17/

Basically you need to handle events in elements not yet created:

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li .del', function(){
```

And in order to use this selector

```
$(this).closest('li')
```

You need to actually put `$(this)`, i.e. `.del` elements inside `li` element

```
var clone = $('li:last').clone().append('<a href="#" class="del">Delete</a>')
clone.appendTo('ul');
```

## Update

```
if(!clone.find('.del')[0]) clone.append('<a href="#" class="del">Delete</a>')

clone.find('.del') // returns elements with del class inside the cloned element
[0]                // gets the first element in these elements, undefined if no del elements found
!                  // negates undefined, i.e. true,

// so code enter if when there is no del element

clone.append('<a...'  // append delete if there is no delete link
```

Comment: I actually did .append('<a href="#" class="del">Delete</a>')
clone.appendTo('ul'); when I was trying to get this to work but it doesn't give the the desired result. The 'Delete' link multiplies with each cloned item. :(

Comment: One more question ... what am I doing wrong when pasting my fiddle link? It yells at me that I need tags to make it a link. You all get it to be a link. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: press ctrl+l highlighting the text to link, but actually you have found a way to bypass an SO validation because when I tried to edit your link I had had to add some code to accompany the link.

Comment: See updated fiddle, I added delete just when it is not present `if(!clone.find('.del')[0]) clone.append('<a href="#" class="del">Delete</a>')`

Comment: This makes me so happy! I wish I could figure this stuff out on my own. If you can indulge me, I'd really like a breakdown explanation of this statement you added  ... thank you SO so much!

Comment: Thank you SO much for the comments in the code ... I will study this and learn.

Answer (score 0):

2 things:

1) You bind your even on load only, so when you create a link, it has no action on it, use [jQuery on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$(document).on('click', '.del',function(){...}
```

2) Closest search for parents, you want the previous `li`, so use `jQuery prev()`

Here a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/56wuv/15/

Comment: Thanks so much, it makes sense when you see it done right. :). One more thing, how can i move the 'delete' link to the right of the text box?

Comment: Well then, instead of `add` use `append` and then change back `.prev('li')` to `.closest('li')`. Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/56wuv/19/